# Conditional formatting to turn a cell a color if it is 1 percentage above or below, Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet with a master tab and 4 additional tabs.  The master is pulling an average percent of the other 4 tabs.  I need a conditional formula to make the cell turn yellow if it is within 1% above or below a goal for the year.  The goal is not always 100%, it would be a goal set in another cell.  For example 90%.  I need the cell to turn yellow if it is 89%.  I need the cell to turn red if it is 88% or lower and green if it is 90% or higher.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

[image: This is What I presume you want]

What you need to do is have overlapping conditional formatting, referencing the value in question. Here's the rules I used for this:

[image: Conditional Formatting Rules]

You can move the rules up and down to show priority - with a different order, some of these colors would alter.

I just realized that the whole equations were cut off. Below is the "green" rule:
[image: Green rule]